# How to create a subsite with site template with REST api?

Tags: rest, csom, site-collection, site-template

I am having a site with some lists and libraries. I have saved this site a site template. Now I want to create a new sub site with programming. I know we can create from the user interface, but I want it from JavaScript REST/CSOM. 
Is it possible to do or no support for this kind of functionality? 
I am looking especially in SharePoint online version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the link below. I have used it before on SharePoint Online. It deploys a new site with a custom site template whenever a new item is created.

https://rogereriksen.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/create-a-sharepoint-site-using-rest-in-workflow-with-sharepoint-designer/

Comment: please add relevant code snippet to the answer along with the link